# Android Studio 0.5.7 : “output path is not specified for modules”

Tags: android

I just recently upgraded to the newest version of Android Studio to 0.5.7, but when I build or try to run my project I get this error:

Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for modules
 "facebook",
"Simple Facebook",
"zweet".
Specify the output path in Configure Project.

However i have use the option "inherit from project" :(

Can you help me ?

Thanks ?